# Evaluate filter matlab function on scipy

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, python, scipy

I want to reproduce the result given by `filter()` MATLAB function using scipy.signal functions. The result is not consistent:

**Matlab example:**

```
bb = 0:.1:9.;

aa = 1;

xx = repmat(0.9234e-18, 100, 1);

[y, zf] = filter(bb,aa,xx);

y(1:10)
zf(1:10)

# print result:
ans =

   1.0e-17 *

         0
    0.0092
    0.0277
    0.0554
    0.0923
    0.1385
    0.1939
    0.2586
    0.3324
    0.4155


ans =

   1.0e-15 *

    0.3781
    0.3780
    0.3779
    0.3776
    0.3772
    0.3767
    0.3762
    0.3755
    0.3748
    0.3740
```

**Python code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter, lfilter_zi

bb = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, .1)[:91]

aa = 1

xx = np.tile(0.9234e-18, (100, 1))

z_i = lfilter_zi(b=bb, a=aa)
y, zf = lfilter(b=bb, x=xx, a=aa, zi=z_i.reshape(len(bb)-1, 1), axis=0)

print(y[:10])
print(zf[:10])

# Print result
[[409.5]
 [409.4]
 [409.2]
 [408.9]
 [408.5]
 [408. ]
 [407.4]
 [406.7]
 [405.9]
 [405. ]]

[[3.7813230e-16]
 [3.7803996e-16]
 [3.7785528e-16]
 [3.7757826e-16]
 [3.7720890e-16]
 [3.7674720e-16]
 [3.7619316e-16]
 [3.7554678e-16]
 [3.7480806e-16]
 [3.7397700e-16]]
```

`Zf's` are the same however `y's` are not the same! Comments?

Comment: *how* are they different? Do you have any indication which one you want to consider correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the Python version you initialize the filter state and in the Matlab version you don't. Hence the result is different.

`lfilter_zi()` calculates the filter state for a unit step response. Your actual signal is 17 orders of magnitude smaller, the initial state will completely dominate the result (for a while).

Comment: If you see in MATLAB, `filter()`  can return `zf` without any initialization. What I understand is that it initializes the state itself(inside the function). However, `lfilter()` needs an initialization to return `zf`

Comment: Matlab assumes zero state, so you can probably reproduce it by making `zi` all zeros

Comment: Thanks, brilliant @Hilmar! I did not found it in the docs!